# Google Datastudio + BQ query + advanced filter on user sample size estimation

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I need some help with building the guage chart with the following requirements

I have a table in bq called dim_table as follows

[image]

I need to provide the Drop-down list on the the dimensions such that when user select the options, i need to refresh the user count percentage.

[image]

For example

When user selects gender as male, country as usa and age_bracket as all of the values, the total user count matching with those values is 12 out of the total value 43 and hence the percentage should 12/43 which is 27.90% in the guage chart

I have the following BQ query

select (cut_value/total_value)*100 as cut_percentage from (select sum(user_count) as cut_value from dim_table where gender in (data_studio_selected_gender_value) and country in (data_studio_selected_country_value) and  age_bracket in (data_studio_selected_age_value) join select select sum(user_count) as total_value from dim_table on 1=1)

Question: How could I integrate the datastudio drop-down list values to the the above query in order to populate the guage chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In data studio have two data sources:

- `dim_table` which is the normal data source
- `total` which is the custom BigQuery: `sum(user_counts) as total, "" as empty from dim_table` (it is also possible to duplicate the first dataset and hide here all fields except `user_counts` and add the extra field `empty`)

Blend these two tables together with the join key `empty`. Generate such a field in the `dim_table` with the formula `""`

Add in the graph or table add a metric with the formula:

```
sum(user_counts)/avg(total)
```

You can apply the normal filter and do not have to worry about parameter to act like filtering.